# DataTrigger Binding IsIndeterminate on Styled Progressbar not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, datatrigger

I've created a template to modify de regular WPF ProgressBar.

Everything is working fine, the problem is with the DataTrigger that starts the animation.
I want to trigger the animation when the property "IsIndeterminate" is set to True.

This Sample is working fine ==> The animation is starting correctly when the view is opened

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource DotMoveProgressBar}" IsIndeterminate="TRUE" />
```

This sample shows the DataTrigger :

```
 <Style x:Key="DotMoveProgressBar" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value> 
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            [... "template" ...]
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsIndeterminate}" Value="True">
                   <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                      <BeginStoryboard>
                         <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                              [...]
                          </Storyboard>
                      </BeginStoryboard>
                   </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
 </Style>
```

To problem comes when I bind a property from my ViewModel.

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource DotMoveProgressBar}" IsIndeterminate="{Binding  IsLoadingData}" />
```

When I set "IsLoadingData" to TRUE in my ViewModel, the animation don't starts.

**The question is** :

Why The anamation is working when IsIndeterminatate is "HardCoded" to TRUE and not when is binded to "IsLoadingData" ?

**/!\ I've tested those things :**

- Binding "IsLoadingData" on other objects works fine. (Tested on button IsEnable property)
- Not working when "IsIndeterminate" is set to true in code-beind.

So I think this is a DataTrigger problem/trick/...

(I wouldn't like to play with visibility unless this is the only solution)

Thanks for your Help !

(Please excuse me for my poor english :-/)

---

**UPDATE** : Thanks to the KingKing's comments this is the next step of the problem :

What I've done :

1. Add a DataTriggerExitActions to the DataTrigger
2. Using TemplateBinding instead of RelativeSource Self

This drives me to the real issue :
This command method binded to a button is working perfectly

```
Public Sub TestFunction()
   IsLoadingData = Not IsLoadingData
End Sub
```

This Async Command Method makes the DataTrigger to not respond correctly

```
Private Async Sub SelectFileToOpenAsync()
   IsLoadingData = True
   Await Task.Run(AddressOf LoadFile)

   Await GenerateScenario()
End Sub
```

Using Async Method seems to makes the DataTrigger to not work correctely

Comment: Your Storyboard has something wrong. It's repeated forever and starts once? That means once it starts nothing stops it. You should ,for example, add an `ExitActions` to stop that storyboard. Then toggling the `IsIndeterminate` should show the desired result.

Comment: Thanks King King ! It's nearly Works but still expecting issues with the binding. Code behind test is working (button that switch the state of `IsIndeterminate` Property) Unfortunatly, binding directly the `IsLoadingData` still not work... I'm testing several things and I'll add a comment to explain the beheviors. Thanks !

Comment: For the binding of `IsLoadingData` I think you should try `{TemplateBinding IsIndeterminate}` instead of {RelativeSource Self} (this was commented by someone before).

Comment: The problem is on my Async method that set the IsLoadingData Property.

Comment: Thanks to KingKing everything is working fine. The problem now comes form this code : `Private Async Sub SelectFileToOpenAsync() IsLoadingData = True [...] End Sub ` The WPF DataTrigger don't react to this changes.

Comment: I don't know well about how async code cannot trigger some animation but looks like it's related to a cross-thread problem (and this is suppressed internally without throwing any error or may be reported somewhere in the Output window). Anyway you can try setting the `IsLoadingData` ***outside*** that async method and right before you call that async method. That way it should work because `IsLoadingData` now is set in the main thread.